# How to validate Input fields in the registration form without page reload?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript

Hi i am trying to validate input fields in Visualforce page but when i click on submit button page reloaded.

**Controller class**:

```
public class register{
  user__c a = new user__c();
  public string username{get;set;}
  public string password{get;set;}
  public string lastname{get;set;}
  public string firstname{get;set;}
  public pagereference post(){
    a.name = firstname;
    a.password__c = password;
    a.lastname__c = lastname;
    a.email__c = username;
    insert a;
    PageReference editPage = page.homepage;
    editPage.setRedirect(true);
    return editPage;
  }
}
```

**Visualforce page**

```
<apex:page controller="register" showHeader="false">
<script>
 var namepattern=/^[a-zA-Z]+$/
 var emailpattern =/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*(\.[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*\.([a-zA-Z]{2,4})$/
function valdation(){
var a = document.getElementById("{!$component.form.fn}");
var b = document.getElementById("{!$component.form.ln}");
var c = document.getElementById("{!$component.form.pw}");
var d = document.getElementById("{!$component.form.un}");
if (a.value==null)
   {
    document.getElementById('err1').innerHTML="Please enter the first name.";
    return false;
   }
   if (b.value=="")
   {
    document.getElementById('err2').innerHTML="Please enter the last name.";
    return false;
   }
   var passid_len = c.value.length;
  if(passid_len == "")
  {  
  document.getElementById('err3').innerHTML="Please enter a password";  
  return false;  
  } 
  if(d.value == ""){
  document.getElementById('err4').innerHTML="Please enter username"; 
  return false;
  }
 }
</script>

<style>
.detail{
margin:0px 0px 90px 350px;
padding:30px 0px 20px 0px;
width:300px;
height:300px;
border:1px solid;
border-radius:5px;
}
.error{
text-align:left;
</style>
<div class="detail" align="center" >
<apex:form id="form" >
<apex:inputtext value="{!firstname}" id="fn" html-placeholder="Firstname" styleclass="input"/>
<div id="err1" class="error"></div>
<apex:inputtext value="{!lastname}" id="ln" html-placeholder="Lastname" styleclass="input"/>
<div id="err2" class="error"></div>
<apex:inputsecret value="{!password}" id="pw" html-placeholder="Password" styleclass="input" />
<div id="err3" class="error"></div>
<apex:inputtext value="{!username}" id="un" html-placeholder="Username" styleclass="input" />
<div id="err4" class="error"></div>
<apex:commandButton action="{!post}" value="submit" onclick="valdation()" id="demo" onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this, 'Lorem ipsum dolor...mauris')" reRender="error" styleclass="input" style="background:blue; color:white;"/>
</apex:form>
</div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I can recommend create action function that executes action **post**, and execute that action function in end of your onclick js method. Also, if you want to rerender somethind with  "error", you need to create apex : output panel , not div, cause rerender only works with native SF components.

Answer (score -1):

Try using action function.Now as you are calling a page reference method it is getting refreshed.

Answer (score -1):

Please remove the action attribute from commandButton keep only onclick function. Create an action function and call that action function from validation method.

```
<apex:commandButton value="submit" onclick="valdation();return false;" id="demo" onmouseover="tooltip.pop(this, 'Lorem ipsum dolor...mauris')" styleclass="input" style="background:blue; color:white;"/>

<apex:actionfunction name="postAF" action="{!post}" rerender="error"/>
```

and from validation JS method call **postAF()**

Comment: Thankyou @nilesh in this case page not reloading validation working fine but finally i need to redirect page its not redirecting

Comment: ok just remove the **rerender="error"** from action function